# <NavHashLink /> : Warning: React does not recognize the `isActive` prop on a DOM element

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-router-hash-link

I'm getting this warning when using `<NavHashLink />` from the react-router-hash-link NPM package, like this:

```
<NavHashLink to='#contact' className='btn btn-primary'>
```

Everything is working as intended but I would like to know what's causing this error and how to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

I have a related issue using 'NavHashLink' with react router v6 and i get rid of the problem by simply using 'HashLink' like this :

```
<HashLink to="/url/#anchor">
   content
</HashLink>
```

hope it will help!